# Hibernate JPA - Map to an embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have a problem concerning hibernate and the mapping to an embeddedId.

The EntityB has a composite key. I want to add a reference (ManyToOne) from  EntityA to one of the primary keys of EntityB.
I tried several suggestions but nothing worked out.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private EntityB enB;
    --- plus constructor/getter and setter for hibernate
}
```

EntityB looks like this

```
@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKey compKey;

    --- some more attributes of the class and the generic methods for hibernate
}

@Embeddable
class CompositePK {

    private int id;
    private int path;
    private int time;
...
}
```

I want to reference from the EntityA to the "id" of EntityB. I hope I explained it understandable. Thanks!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611619/onetomany-and-composite-primary-keys

Comment: you might wanna check this  http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: Well...sorry for the duplicate and thanks for the quick responses. The suggested solution of Rene worked out for me :)