# JPA: @OneToMany mapping and composite primary key - Logical column not found error

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have issues with mapping OneToMany foreign key to a composite primary key. I have already tried many solutions, including this post [@OneToMany and composite primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611619/onetomany-and-composite-primary-keys).

So the situation is:

I have two entities, say, Box & Color and the composite primary key is on the child side (Color).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "box")
data class Box(
        @Id
        var id: Int = 0,
        ...
       @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumns(
                JoinColumn(name = "box_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                JoinColumn(name = "locale", referencedColumnName = "locale"))
        val colors: List<Color> = emptyList(),
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "color")
data class Color(
        
        @EmbeddedId
        var colorId: ColorId? = null,
) : Serializable

@Embeddable
data class ColorId(
        var id: Int = 0,
        @Column(name = "locale", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        var locale: Locale = Locale.Germany
) : Serializable
```

So, in the Box entity, I am trying to create an OneToMany mapping between Box & Color entities. For this should I use the composite primary key of the Color entity? If I try to join columns to the composite primary key(as I have done in the Box entity) I do get an error saying - unable to locate the logical column "locale".

How can I resolve this?

Or what is the neat solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`OneToMany` mapping will connect one `Box` with many `Colors`. Therefore, each `Color` needs to point to a `Box`, so each `Color` has a foreign key referencing the **primary key of `Box`** (of `Int` type).

[image]

#### @OneToMany as an owning side

In your mapping, you should use a single join column since this join column will be placed in the `color` table:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "box")
data class Box(
        @Id
        var id: Int = 0,
        ...

        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "box_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        var colors: MutableList<Color> = mutableListOf()
)
```

You can check-out the working sample (Kotlin and Java) in my [github repo](https://github.com/pwegrzynowicz/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/jpa-box-colors).

### @OneToMany as an inverse (mapped-by) side

#### Database perspective

`@OneToMany` as an **owning side** and `@OneToMany` as an **inverse side** (with a complimentary mandatory `@ManyToOne`) produce the same database schema - a foreign key on the `color` table. That's why `@JoinColumn` annotation looks the same in both cases, no matter which side you place it on - the goal is to produce a foreign key on the `many` side.

#### Application perspective

The **difference** in 'owning-side' is in an application perspective. **JPA/hibernate saves the relationships only from the owning side.**

So, if you change the owning side, you must set up this side (attribute) in your application code. In this case, you must set up `Box` in `Color`, otherwise, JPA/hibernate will not create a relationship (even though you added your `Colors` to `Box`). Moreover, it will not raise any exception, just the relationship will not be created. Next time, you will retrieve your `Box` from a database, the `Color` list will be empty.

You can check-out the working samples and see the difference in ownership in my [github repo](https://github.com/pwegrzynowicz/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/jpa-box-colors).

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "box")
data class Box(
        @Id
        var id: Int = 0,
        ...

        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy="box")
        var colors: MutableList<Color> = mutableListOf(),
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "color")
data class Color(
        
        @EmbeddedId
        var colorId: ColorId? = null,
        
        // the owning side is changed, therefore you MUST set the box in Color
        // otherwise the relationship in a database will not be saved (!)
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "box_id")
        var box: Box? = null
) : Serializable
```

### Other possible problems

Since you struggle with a `OneToMany` relationship, it might be useful for you to consider some other possible problems in this model.

#### Locale non-insertable and non-updatable

Another problem, you may encounter, is saving `locale` in `ColorId` as you marked it as `non-insertable` and `non-updatable`. If this is on purpose that's fine (in that case all your colors must be pre-inserted into the database, or they will be inserted without Locale).

Please, keep in mind, that setting Locale.GERMAN has no effect on a database in this case. It will be silently ignored and if you don't have such a color in a database, it will be inserted with null.

#### Color assigned to only one box

If you model this relationship, you make a single Color (like Black in German) be assigned to **only one** Box. It sounds a bit unnatural. Usually, I would assume Black can be assigned to many Boxes. So, it would be a `ManyToMany` relationship. Again, if this is on purpose, that's fine!

#### ColorId as a primary key

It's also a bit unnatural to have `Locale` as a part of a primary key in `Color` -- Black in German and Black in English as different colors? The colors themselves are locale-independent. The name of a color is locale-dependent, but it's more a matter of UI. Again, if this is on purpose, that's fine! After all, it's your business model!

Comment: But Color has composite primary key (id & locale). Shouldn't locale be considered in this case?

Comment: No, you have many on the Color side and one on the Box side. The foreign key is on the many side and references the one side. So, the foreign key will be placed in Color and will reference the Box id, which is a simple int.

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi my code is fine and tested. :) Check out the github repo (in Java for now, but the mappings are exactly the same): https://github.com/pwegrzynowicz/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/jpa-box-colors, the approach with `ManyToOne` and `mappedBy` in `OneToMany` will work too. But it changes the owning side of a relationship, so it depends on what the author prefers and what his use-case is.

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi And added Kotlin samples to the repo. You can clearly see it's working. Plus, you can see how changing the ownership impacts the code.

Comment: You are right. I must've misread your post. But one point though, the strategy you are using here is unidirectional which is NOT that performant. I would still prefer a `@ManyToOne` on the Color entity (may be a bidirectional mapping with `@OneToMany`  with the `mappedBy` attribute to specify the other side owns the join). It is also more performant than the unidirectional join.

Answer (score 1):

Before providing you a solution, i would like to give you more info on the `@OneToMany` and the `@JoinColumns` annotation.

A `@OneToMany`mapping symbolizes the fact that the Entity which has that mapping applied has **many** references to the other entity.

i.e. A `Box` has many references to `Color(s)` in your case.

Now to model this, I would suggest you reverse the mapping and use `@ManyToOne` on the Color entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "color")
data class Color(
        
        @EmbeddedId
        var colorId: ColorId? = null,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "box_id"), //referencedColumnName is not needed here as it is inferred as "id"
        var box: Box? = null
) : Serializable
```

Because the foreign key is supposed to be in Color. You cannot have foreign keys from Box to Color as there may be more than one Color.

Also, note that it is *not* `@JoinColumns`, it is the singular `@JoinColumn`. You need the plural version if the `Box` entity contains a `Composite Primary Key`.

With that being said, you can all together ignore the `@OneToMany` mapping, because if you need to get all Colors of a Box, you can and should in my opinion, simply use the `Query` API.

A `@OneToMany` mapping in this case would only be a convenience. But if you insist on having the `@OneToMany` mapping then you can use the following.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "box")
data class Box(
        @Id
        var id: Int = 0,
        ...
       @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy="box") // mappedBy will use the "box" reference from the Color Class
        val colors: List<Color> = emptyList(),
)
```

Comment: In @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY) only box_id joining is done..,  @JoinColumn(name = "box_id") : how about the other property locale . Joining locale is required?

Comment: @SGuru in your question, the `locale` field is in the `Color` entity. Why do you think `locale` is needed to refer to a `Box` entity?

Answer (score -1):

You have two options. Either define a join table `@JoinTable(name = "color_box_assignment", joinColumns = ...)` or use an inverse mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "color")
data class Color(
        
        @EmbeddedId
        var colorId: ColorId? = null,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
        @JoinColumns(
            JoinColumn(name = "box_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            JoinColumn(name = "locale", referencedColumnName = "locale"))
        var box: Box? = null
) : Serializable
```

Comment: by having an inverse mapping, will the composite key be taken care? And how about the solution presented by Patrycja in the below post? That works as well, but I am unsure if composite key is considered there?

Comment: Yeah it will handle composite keys. The answer Partycja gave is IMO not correct but goes into the same direction as mine.

Comment: I do get the following error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: locale in box

Comment: What mapping are you using now? Approach this step by step. First try adding just the `box` association to `Color`. This should just work. Then add the inverse `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "box") Set<Color> colors` on the other side.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov my solution is fine and working, check out the sample code (in Java for now, but mappings are exactly the same): https://github.com/pwegrzynowicz/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/jpa-box-colors, the approach with `ManyToOne` will work too, but it changes the `owning` side of a relationship. So, it depends on a use-case of the author.

Comment: The OP mentioned he has a composite primary key which you are not mapping

Comment: @ChristianBeikov looks like you didn't see my code and didn't read my post. Please, take a closer look and you'll see that `@JoinColum` represents the FK column. In this case, the composite key is not an FK and it shouldn't be used in the `@JoinColumn` annotation. That's why the original code doesn't work, and your code will not work either. It will raise **the same error** as in the question - `unable to locate the logical column "locale"`.

Comment: I was of the impression that the OP want this, but if it is not, your solution is fine.